# Bitrix 24 - Adding custom field to product list on deal

Tags: customization, product, bitrix

I'd like to add a new field to product list available to be variable to each deal (like quantity, for example). Is it possible to be done? Thanks in advance.

This is the moment I need this new field to appear:
[image]

Comment: Hi, are you talking about Self-hosted or Cloud edition?

Comment: Hi Rafail, i´m using Cloud Edition.

Comment: It is not possible to add custom fields to product list in cloud edition.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new fields to products in both cloud and on-prem versions. You can view these special fields while adding product to DEAL cards, but it is not possible to view those under the product tab of DEAL cards.

You need to develop a Bitrix24 application for that purpose utilizing the REST API or B24 JS library.